# Windows X2Go using ssh config file

Tags: ssh, windows, x2go

To connect to our servers we use X2Go. The setup is a little bit more sophisticated due to the use of a proxy. The proxy is setup properly and works when I connect via ssh in the powershell. I also installed the ssh keys and I dont have to give the password. The problem is now that I need to use this ssh config file. Before you ask me to use the proxy in the session settings of X2Go, here comes the second kicker.

On Windows I recently had to start adding the `-m hmac-sha2-512` to avoid the corrupt MAC error. This option I can not pass in the session settings.

A colleague (that uses linux) told me the that the "Try auto login ... " checkbox in the session settings supposedly reads the .ssh/config file. On Windows it does not seem to work.

Comment: Probably this post is more for "Super User" than "Unix & Linux"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to use an SSH tunnel. I got the inspiration for this from [here](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win/issues/10).

First, one needs to set up the ssh config file as desired. Here, I use the cipher option and a proxy:

```
Host remote*
    HostName %h.full.qualified.domain
    ProxyJump my.proxy
    User <user_name>
    MACs hmac-sha2-512

Host my.proxy
    Hostname proxy.full.qualified.domain
    User <user_name>
    MACs hmac-sha2-512
```

Then, one can open an SSH tunnel in PowerShell like this:

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:22 <targe_remote_machine>
```

Important: the PowerShell window with this tunnel connection needs to stay open.
In the X2Go session setting, we must give `localhost` as the host and `2222` as the port.

To me, this workaround is a blueprint for doing whatever fancy things in the SSH configuration and using it in X2Go through the established tunnel.

[Edit] I realize just now that I have read this [page](https://forum.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/t/how-to-configure-a-x2go-client-using-a-ssh-tunnel/1087) but did not understand it even though it gives the same solution.